# Move element out of scrolled div

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shortList" id="unselShortList">
   <div id="Value1">A</div>
   <div id="Value2">B</div>
    <div id="Value3">C</div>
    <div id="Value4">D</div>
    <div id="Value5">E</div>
    <div id="Value6">F</div>
    <div id="Value7">G</div>
    <div id="Value8">H</div>
   <div id="SubmitValue">
      <div id="submit"><a href = "#">OK</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#unselShortList {
    background-color: red; 
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;    
}
#submit {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/iyogesh/4sxNg/

'OK' Hyperlink is coming inside div.
How can I move 'OK' link out of scrolled div and show it after div using CSS without changing html structure?

Comment: You can visually move element outside, by setting negative `bottom:`, but since you have scrollable element, you will not make it without changing HTML structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cocoa_beans/4sxNg/5/)

add a parent element

```
<div id="unselShortList">
    <div class="shortList" >
        <div id="Value1">A</div>
        <div id="Value2">B</div>
        <div id="Value3">C</div>
        <div id="Value4">D</div>
        <div id="Value5">E</div>
        <div id="Value6">F</div>
        <div id="Value7">G</div>
        <div id="Value8">H</div>
    <div id="SubmitValue">
        <div id="submit"><a href = "#">OK</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#unselShortList {
position: relative;
padding-bottom:31px;
}
.shortList{
height: 150px;
background-color: #33cccc;
overflow: scroll;
margin-bottom:25px;
}
#submit {
position: absolute;
}
#SubmitValue{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Nb. this is a good answer but does contravene to OP stating: `without changing html structure`

Comment: The structure is not changed,a parent element is added,that's the only change in structure + css changes to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

## You CANT

(unfortunately)

Because you've specified `overflow` on the parent container, you cannot position child content outside of its limits. You can see the effect of this [here (without)](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4sxNg/2/) vs [here (with)](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4sxNg/3/)

In this case you will need to implement a change in your HTML, or look at other styling options- such as overlaying the button in the top right of the `div` or using javascript to reposition/add an element into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 #submit {
    position: fixed;
}
```